# Issue dispaying values after PHP submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, nan

I am using a PHP voting script http://codecanyon.net/item/thumbsup/full_screen_preview/50411 called Thumbs Up. I am very new to PHP and everything is working great apart from the displaying of the votes.

Upon voting the database gets updated and there is a postback that updates the number of votes. I have tried multiple ways to display the results, but it keeps returning NaN. If I reload the page then the values appear successfully.

I am loading the results table in upon click and trying to return the results but I am having no luck. I loop through the `<li>` and am storing the results in an array.

This returns NaN instead of the values. If I reload the page the value are there and updated. It seems that there is a delay in the php postback that is resulting in this problem. I did try adding a delay to the ajax call but it still returns NaN.

code:

I am storing each result and am storing the values in an array

```
var resultVoteOne = voteOneDigit / total * 100;
var arrValues = [resultVoteOne]
```

I am displaying the results in a bar chart:

```
$('.extras_result p.vote1 span').append(arrValues[0] + '%');

$(".extras_result").each(function() {
    var length = $(this).find("span").html();
    $(this).find("p").animate({'width':length}, 1000, function() {
  $(this).find("span").fadeIn(800);
    });
});
```

If I reload the page after voting the graph updates successfully.

On click I tried using ajax to update the values but still no luck :(

```
$('.containers input').on('click', function() { 
    $.ajax({
    url:'results.php',
    cache:false,
    success: function(response) {
    $('.voteResults').html(response);
    }
    });
});
```

I appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: Do you have this example online? Can you show also backend code?

Comment: The "response" var could be in a html format or something else, thus displaying a NotANumber (NaN) error. Have you tried returning it in json for example?

Answer (score 0):

use async: false in your ajax method first
Might this can solve your problem just blank the voteRequest before displaying it

```
$('.voteResults').html('');
$('.voteResults').html(response);
```

Whatever comes through the ajax is converted into string so you have to typecast in javascript before using it as a number calculation otherwise it will give you the result NaN

Comment: Sadly I dont have an example online. I tried async: false but still no luck. Thanks for replying :)

Comment: just type cast whatever you are getting from ajax before using it